# Can off-shell corrections to processes lead to corrections on number of jets distributions? (both for MC and Data)

Tags: particle-physics

I was looking at the modeling of ttW production (but the question is general) and came upon an off-shell corrections paper. As I am no expert on MC generators, I am not sure if these off-shell corrections can lead to different amounts of radiation compared to an on-shell sample.

My intuition says that maybe a Sudakov factor contribution might shift slightly and because of the Pt shift of jets the PS might differ but I do not expect large differences in number of jets as I can't think of an off-shell channel diagram that would differ significantly in extra radiation. Is this the case or are there examples where one does see noticeable differences (only in the modeling/in data as well)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.